# Can granfana read data from Azure Time Series Insights database?

Tags: azure, grafana

I see references to various azure databases and grafana, but its not clear if grafana can connect to Azure Time Series Insights database.  Is this possible?  Do any of the existing azure-related plugins work?

Comment: Try: https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource

Comment: The Azure Monitor Data Source plugin at [grafana.com/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource) currently only supports "Azure Monitor, Azure Log Analytics and Application Insights", and not Azure TSI. 


Grafana support for Azure TSI has been requested at [Support for Azure Time Series Insights #90](https://github.com/grafana/azure-monitor-datasource/issues/90).